# Persistent holes in mesh

Tags: python, mesh, scripting, modifiers, geometry-nodes

I have an object, like a cube. I will move other meshes through it, or fire particles at it. I want theses things to pass through the object, leaving a hole where they went through without needing a ton of Boolean modifiers. Basically, turning this:[image: before] into this: [image: after] just by moving the cylinder. Ideally it would separate the cube into 2 different objects for physics, but it is OK if not. I will accept any answer, including geometry nodes, and scripting, but not the Boolean modifier.

NOTE: I will also accept a shader that makes it look like there is a hole in the object.

Comment: But no boolean... https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rQWG.gif

Comment: @lemon you're such a tease!  Do I need to play the timpani?

Comment: @james_t, no! we said "no boolean"!